# Is it always only 3 extranormal skills?

Tags: d6-system

I've only seen a handful of D6 books so far (so only a very small part of the over 3000 that were created thanks to the D6 system). But in these I noticed that there was always 3 skills for each extranormal attribute (so 3 skills per type of supernatural you could say).

So my question is: Is that only coincidence? Or is that like a core element for the D6 system that there is always only 3 skills for each type of supernatural (min and max 3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is coincidence

See:

- Magic & Psionics of [D6 Adventure](https://drive.google.com/a/trimble.com/folderview?id=0B2IjSz8Neh5qfldWMFhDcjdyRUFMVEMzUXUwbjZxYUhJZ2JwaC13bEhTUkVvcGpMMlRzSkk&usp=sharing#) (p13)
- Magic of [D6 Fantasy](https://drive.google.com/a/trimble.com/folderview?id=0B2IjSz8Neh5qfldWMFhDcjdyRUFMVEMzUXUwbjZxYUhJZ2JwaC13bEhTUkVvcGpMMlRzSkk&usp=sharing#) (p13)

In general the three skills per extranormal attribute boil down to having tools to:

- gather information
- help with defending/protecting yourself & others
- give you a novel way to attack/deal damage to your enemies

Comment: tnx that solved my question. Then the eamples I had looked at were as I had hoped only coincidences. Have a follow up question there though currently trying to get to formulate it correctly so that it follows the rules of stackexchange